# Experiencing Scotland in the Winters

Tags: uk, international-travel, winter, scotland

We are a group of 4 adults travelling from India to experience for ourselves the fabled beauty of Scotland!

We plan to travel either at the end of November, around Thanksgiving, or at the end of December, during Christmas and New Year. We know while it is going to be cold and wet especially in the highlands (and we plan to drive ourselves), we really want to put up either a walk / a trek / or a land rover safari on our itinerary.

It will be really helpful to know,

1) Which time of year is better to visit Scotland, so the beauty of the highland is at its peak, end of Nov vs end of Dec?

2) What are ways we can explore the highlands?

Coming from a tropical country, (despite having trekked on the Himalayas), we would like a more info (such as a website) to guide us on the weather, Highland Safari(s), and Scottish Culture & its Traditions.

Comment: You mentioned Thanksgiving - just in case you didn't already know, Thanksgiving is an American holiday that isn't celebrated in the UK / Europe (except for a few small events by or for Americans, probably same in India). So if you choose November, don't expect any Thanksgiving cultural experience (but if you're around on [5th November you might see fireworks and bonfires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Fawkes_Night) - maybe less a big deal in Scotland than England but they do have [several public fireworks displays](https://www.visitscotland.com/blog/scotland/bonfire-night-fireworks/))

Comment: Also St Andrew's Day on 30th November, it will have some special events and a chance to experience Scottish culture.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend end of December rather than November, as you will be able to experience Hogmanay, the traditional Scottish New Year celebrations.

Generally the Highlands have most snow around January/February, but you could encounter it or rain, sun or wind at any point in your visit, so be aware that layers and waterproofing are essential. Bring hats, gloves, waterproof jackets, fleeces, hand warmers, and a guide!

As regards packages, there are ones that will include the West Coast and Skye, Inverness and Loch Ness, the Cairngorm range, whisky tours, waterfall and canyon hikes, mountain and Munro bagging, as well as cultural events like ceilidhs and so on, so you'll really need to think about what you want. Scotland's tourist industry is second to none though, so you will have no problem finding a tour, package or itinerary to suit. If you wanted one of the really big events, like Edinburgh's Hogmanay, then getting tickets can be a challenge - but I'd only recommend it if you like crowds anyway.